# Using global $post v/s $GLOBALS['post']

Tags: globals, coding-standards

It's probably more of a PHP question, but I would like to know if there are any differences in using

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

when compared to

```
echo $GLOBALS['post']->ID;
```

to access the ID of a post in WordPress.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3574125/1370034) on SO suggests that the first method is quicker to process, while the second method is quicker to write.

I also noticed that the first method is often mentioned in the Codex while the second method is mentioned on [`the_content` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)  page.

Is this only a matter of preference? Or does it come to performance and security too?

Thanks

Comment: Avoid globals when you can. In your case, you can use [get_the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) instead

Comment: Yes, I usually use `get_the_ID()`, but any particular reason for avoiding using globals?

Comment: A global variable can be removed or changed in future updates, while a function will always return what you expect. And if it gets deprecated, you'll get notified about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference when you are using just `echo`. What works different is `unset()`:

```
function test_unset_1()
{
    global $post;
    unset( $post );
}
function test_unset_2()
{
    unset( $GLOBALS['post'] );
}

test_unset_1();
echo $GLOBALS['post']->ID; // will work

test_unset_2();
echo $GLOBALS['post']->ID; // will fail
```

The reason is that `unset()` destroys just the local reference in the first case and the real global object in the second.

For readability use always `$GLOBALS['post']`. It is easier to see where the variable is coming from.